# Is there a single word for both "atom" and "ion"?

Tags: single-word-requests, science

When I'm writing about atoms, often what I'm writing about applies to (monatomic) ions too. It's slightly annoying to add "(or ions)" after every mention of atoms, where a word that refers to both atoms and ions would be ideal. Does such a word exist?

There is "element", but often this is used to refer to multiple atoms of the same element, whereas "atom" and "ion" clearly refer to a single atom or ion.

An example: "An isotope is an atom (or ion) of the same element but with a different number of neutrons."

Comment: Apologies if the english stackexchange isn't the right place. Please tell me if it isn't, or if this question is better suited for the physics or chemistry stackexchange.

Comment: Physics or chemistry ... yes.  As at any site in SE, showing your research is encouraged!

Comment: Atoms and ions are very different things. _An Atom is the smallest particle of an element which can take part in a chemical reaction whereas the Ions are not capable of taking part in chemical reactions. Ions can, however, exist independently in a solution, whereas, Atoms may or may not be able to exist independently._ [Atoms/Ions](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/difference-between-atom-and-ion/). I think you are stuck with having to mention both.

Comment: @terdon Na+ is an atom that has lost an electron. It is no longer a neutral atom.

Comment: @NigelJ d'oh! You're quite right.

Comment: Could please [edit] your question and give a specific example? Show us a sentence where you would use the word.

Comment: @terdon Now that you mention it, I don't have many examples where I was using (or ions) correctly. Is the example I have provided correct?

Comment: 'Isotope' refers to proton/neutron number. During radioactive decay, elements change from one element to another as they lose particles. I don't think 'isotope' means what you want.

Comment: @NigelJ Yes, I understand how isotopes refer to proton/neutron number and how unstable isotopes change elements.  I had removed some information from my example which I thought was unnecessary.

Comment: In your sentence you do not have to mention the ion. If you are talking about proton/neutron number, then the different electron number (of the ion) is irrelevant.

Comment: @NigelJ Maybe, but mentioning just an atom makes it unclear whether it's the same for ions (in my opinion), so I'd like to make it clear.

Comment: Now there is a example sentence I think you simply need the word **form**:  *Isotope are **forms** of the same element but with a different number of neutrons.*

Comment: A potential short form would be to write "(charged) atom of the same element". This is perfectly appropriate in academic writing in my field and would include both atoms and ions.

Comment: Both 'ionised atom' and 'non-ionised atom' are used. 'Atom' is already a hypernym.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I see you’ve already accepted an answer, and I’m not a frequenter on EL&U, but here are my suggestions: the International Bureau of Weights and Measures refers to both atoms and ions (in the SI Brochure) with the umbrella term *elementary entities*, where those entities are to be specified; also, with enough context, *particles* should suffice, in my opinion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not all ions are atoms (see quote in my answer).

Comment: @Nigel J 'Atom' is a hypernym of  'ionised atom' and 'non-ionised atom', as I said. OP narrows the question in the first sentence:  '(monatomic) ions'. My degrees _are_ in chemistry.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor the context would have to be quite details to exclude molecules as well as subatomic particles, and calling atoms *elementary*, while correct for at least one definition of elementary, isn't very clear

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this requires knowledge of Chemistry more than knowledge of English.

Comment: @NigelJ, Ions can too participate in chemical reactions. In fact, there is an entire branch of chemistry devoted to chemical reactions involving ions, namely electrochemistry (whose related engineering is responsible for things like batteries and chrome plating). Furthermore, the Bronsted-Lowry model for acid/base reactions is predicated on the idea that hydrogen ions can react chemically, at least in aqueous solution. I know you are just quoting an outside source, but I don't don't have the necessary account to take it up with them.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

My suggestion is that at the **first** mention of the word *atom*, you add a qualifier like *neutral and/or ionized*. For example, you can use one of the following constructions:

*...neutral or ionized atoms...

...both neutral and ionized atoms...

...atoms, whether neutral or ionized, ...

...atoms, both neutral and ionized, ...*

**After that**, just use the word *atom*. The reader will know that you mean both neutral and ionized species.

In parts of the text where it is important to distinguish electrically neutral species from electrically charged ones, use the expressions *neutral atoms* and *ionized atoms*.

**Discussion**

In many (though not all) contexts, the word *atom* **already** denotes both the ionized and the non-ionized species. This is why when it is important to emphasize the status with respect to electric neutrality, we speak of ***neutral atoms*** and ***ionized atoms***.

I agree that the **default** reading of the word *atom* is one where it is electrically neutral. But I disagree that electric neutrality is part of the very definition of that word.

(As others have emphasized already, an *ion* is not necessarily an ionized ***atom***; an ionized ***molecule*** is also an ion.)

Wikipedia is of course not itself a reputable source, but consider the second sentence in its [article on atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom) (boldfaced emphasis mine):

> Every solid, liquid, gas, and plasma is composed of **neutral or ionized atoms**.

Here are some examples of similar usage from published sources (boldfaced emhases mine):

> *A rare-earth or actinide **atom**, **whether neutral or ionized**, very often possesses several electrons outside closed shells...* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=1VQABAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR12&dq=%22neutral%20or%20ionized%22&pg=PR12#v=onepage&q=%22neutral%20or%20ionized%22&f=false)
> *identified by the spectra of their **neutral or ionized atoms*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=qKRqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22neutral+or+ionized%22&dq=%22neutral+or+ionized%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil1YDq_YLbAhUCd98KHfQ3ADkQ6AEInAEwGw)
> *Tables of Spectral Lines of **Neutral and Ionized Atoms*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=2VvtBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR2&dq=%22neutral%20and%20ionized%22&pg=PR2#v=onepage&q=%22neutral%20and%20ionized%22&f=false)
> *the fact that **both neutral and ionized atoms** are emitting* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=qe8PQuxz4ncC&lpg=PA31&dq=%22neutral%20and%20ionized%20atoms%22&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q=%22neutral%20and%20ionized%20atoms%22&f=false)

In all of the examples, it is clear that the authors say that atoms can be both neutral and ionized, which wouldn't make much sense if atoms were neutral by definition; see below for more on that.

**Zumdahl's *Chemistry***

To be sure, there seem to be examples where electric neutrality seems to be part of the definition of the word *atom*. For example, in the university-level introductory-chemistry textbook by [Zumdahl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/061852844X), we find the following:

> *Since atoms were known to be electrically neutral...* (p. 46)

But Zumdahl is not consistent in this usage. Consider his definition of an ion:

> *An **ion** is an atom or group of atoms that has a net positive or negative charge.* (p. 56)

This definition would make no sense if atoms had to be electrically neutral by definition; if they did, it would not be possible for an atom to have a net positive or negative charge. To drive this point home, note how strange the above definition becomes if *atom* is qualified by *neutral*:

<sup>?</sup>*An **ion** is a neutral atom or group of atoms that has a net positive or negative charge.*

'How can a neutral atom have a net charge??' is what we immediately want to ask. In order for the sentence to make sense, we would want to rephrase, e.g. as follows:

*An **ion** is a neutral atom or group of atoms that has acquired a net positive or negative charge.*

Now it's OK, because a thing can change group membership after something happens to it; compare with *an odd number is an even number to which we added 1.*

Similarly, if it were really the case that atoms were electrically neutral by definition, it would be a bit strange to talk about *neutral atoms*—after all, what other kind could there be? And yet, we find the following in Zumdahl (boldfaced emphases mine):

> *In a **neutral atom** of each element, how many electrons are present?* (p. 71)
> *...the symbol and mass number of a **neutral atom** whose total mass of its electrons is...* (p. 74)
> *Note that the first electron is removed from a **neutral atom** (Al), ...* (p. 309)
> *The number of valence electrons on the free **neutral atom**...* (p. 364)

Zumdahl is definitely not alone in using the expression *neutral atom*. It is in fact widely used in scientific literature, as a search in google books can easily verify (see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neutral+atom%22&btnG=Search&num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks)).

Comment: As the OP now stands, your answer is a good fit and I have up-voted it. As it was first asked (in the first of its many edits) this answer would not have been correct.

Comment: Similar to ions are radicals. These are formed when input energy disturbs a covalent bond. They _can be_ electrically neutral and are not necessarily ions.

Comment: An alternative would be to use an introductory sentence like: "Unless specified otherwise, we will henceforth use the term 'atom' for both neutral and ionized atoms" or similar.

Answer (score 8):

**particle**

I admit **particle** is a pretty overloaded term, which indeed is very often applied to subatomic world, but I don't think that precludes its use for molecular/atomic level entities.

The following BBC example for Chemistry students below seems to say same...

> Ions are electrically charged **particles** formed when atoms lose or gain electrons. They have the same electronic structures as noble gases.
> — [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/science/add_edexcel/ionic_compounds/ionicrev1.shtml)

And from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle):

> In the physical sciences, a particle (or corpuscule in older texts) is a small localized object to which can be ascribed several physical or chemical properties such as volume , density or mass.  **They vary greatly in size or quantity, from subatomic particles like the electron, to microscopic particles like atoms and molecules, to macroscopic particles like powders and other granular materials.**
>
> [...]
>
> The term 'particle' is rather general in meaning, and is refined as needed by various scientific fields.

---

**Note**:

Above answer was written before the OP supplied the sample sentence.  In hindsight I think he was not really asking about ions/atoms but rather needed the word **form**. e.g.  *Isotope are forms of the same element ...* I'm leaving it as I think  discussion on whether it can be use at an atomic/molecular level or better reserved for sub-atomic level only is interesting.

Comment: Ions are _not_ particles! Or, rather, some few are (H+, for instance) but you can have absolutely enormous ions, consisting of multiple atoms.

Comment: @terdon In the physical sciences, a particle (or corpuscule in older texts) is a small localized object to which can be ascribed several physical or chemical properties such as volume , density or mass. They vary greatly in size or quantity, from subatomic particles like the electron, to microscopic particles like atoms and molecules, to macroscopic particles like powders and other granular materials.  So says wikipedia

Comment: Hmm. I'd like to see a reference for that, if you have one. I am a biologist and I have _never_ seen the term used as you describe. Perhaps it's specific to another field? If I were to call a multi-atomic ion a particle, I'd get in trouble.

Comment: @178865 an ion is any chemical moiety (*moiety*, by the way, is a good word here) with a charge. That can range in size from a single proton (H+) to huge, multi-atomic molecules. Calling them particles would suggest (to my mind, at least, although k1eran says otherwise) that you are referring to sub-atomic particles.

Comment: The word 'particle' does not mean _just_ atoms and ions. It could refer to a quark, a lepton, a muon or a tau. To use it in reference _only_ to _chemically_ interacting species (atoms and ions) would not be correct.

Comment: even the '.photon' can be a particle

Comment: Here's a list of common [polyatomic ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyatomic_ion): http://www.chemistry.wustl.edu/~edudev/LabTutorials/PeriodicProperties/Ions/ions.html. You wouldn't call any of those "particles".

Comment: @terdon What if they are in ionic liquids or ionic solutions ?

Comment: What do you mean? That won't make them particles.

Comment: @terdon I am going by the definition I edited in just now from wikipedia *a small localized object to which can be ascribed several physical or chemical properties* were a molecule is split-up into ions I think one could say they are small localized objects

Comment: I see what you mean (and have removed my downvote) but I would strongly urge the OP not to use this term. Unless made very, very clear, the word *particle* will be taken to mean *subatomic particle* if discussing atoms.

Comment: @terdon I agree. 'Particles' means stuff you bump into in the Atlas detector on the Large Hadron Collider.

Answer (score 7):

Monatomic ions are a type of atom.

You seem to be asking for a word that encompasses both monatomic ions and neutral atoms. That word is **atom**.

Answer (score 3):

Charged ions and stable atoms are different things physically and chemically.

They require to be identified separately.

We are not, here, comparing apples and oranges or cats and dogs. We are referring, as it were, to dogs and apples. So they have to be identified as separate items.

> An atom can be an ion, but **not all ions are atoms**. The difference between an atom and an ion has to do with net electrical charge.
>
> An ion is a particle or collection of particles with a **net positive or negative charge.**
>
> An atom is the basic unit of an element. The identity of an element is determined by the number of positively charged protons in the atom’s nucleus. A stable atom contains the **same number of electrons as protons and no net charge**.

[Science Notes](https://sciencenotes.org/what-is-the-difference-between-an-atom-and-an-ion/)

---

**NOTE** : This answer was to a previous edit of the OP. I have up-voted @linguisticturn because I believe that it is now a good fit for the question as it currently stands.

Comment: So the word I'm looking for doesn't exist because it shouldn't exist?

Comment: @178865 It would cause confusion if it did exist, so let's not invent it.

Comment: The dogs and apples comparison isn't very fair, you get the ion by taking out or adding an electron or proton (so the charge changes, *in case of monatomic ions*). A better comparison would be softdrinks before and after [the sugar tax came in the UK](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/business/news/sugar-tax-soft-drinks-coca-cola-irn-bru-ribena-fanta-lucozade-a8291421.html), the only difference is the sugar content (sugar representing the charge in the atom/ion comparison).

Comment: @JJJ At the atomic level, the removal, or addition, of an electron is of such significance that it transforms a neutral entity into a charged entity - and makes chemistry possible. Sweetening a drink just does not bear any comparison to the enormity of the atomic change, in my view.

Comment: @NigelJ just to play devil's advocate, electrons have -e charge, up quarks have +2/3e charge, both are subatomic particles. And, indeed, there are [more quarks, leptons and bosons with different mass and charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subatomic_particle#/media/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg), but all of them (as far as I know) are subatomic particles.

Comment: @JJJ Agreed. They are 'subatomic' not 'atomic'. So, what is an 'atomic particle' may I ask ?

Comment: @NigelJ as far as I know 'atomic particle' isn't regularly used. If atomic particles was commonly used for atom-size particles, it might be an answer, but as far as I see (and searched) it isn't, unfortunately.

Comment: "We are referring to dogs and apples." "An atom can be an ion, but not all ions are atoms." So can dogs be apples? Or can apples be dogs? I'm confused.

Comment: @mjaggard You have spotted a flaw in my argument. I could waffle on about 'the weird world of quantum mechanics in which dogs can change into apples' - but I won't. My analogy was a bad one - conceded :)

Answer (score 3):

In the *vast majority* of situations that apply to both atoms and ions, stating only atoms should be sufficient, as most people with a basic chemistry/physics background should understand it applies to both. (unless it also includes polyatomic ions)

In my opinion, the only time the distinction is warranted is for a case that applies only to ions and *not* neutral atoms.

Using terms like 'particle' or 'chemical species' are ok, but risk being too general and may harm the clarity of what you are trying to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

The word "species" and phrase "chemical species" are quite general and might serve your purpose. In chemistry, species can apply to atoms, ions, molecules, and radicals. The word "species" is used many times in the IUPAC Gold Book and chemical species is defined as:

> **chemical species**: An ensemble of chemically identical molecular entities that can explore the same set of molecular energy levels on the time scale of the experiment. The term is applied equally to a set of chemically identical atomic or molecular structural units in a solid array...

k1eran suggested "particle", which very general and is used by IUPAC Gold Book in the definition of both ion and atom:

> **ion**: An atomic or molecular particle having a net electric charge.
>
> **atom**: Smallest particle still characterizing a chemical element. It consists of a nucleus of a positive charge ( is the proton number and the elementary charge) carrying almost all its mass (more than 99.9%)and electrons determining its size.

Another phrase used throughout the IUPAC Gold Book that could apply is "molecular entity", which, according to the definition, includes atoms. You can see it used in the definition of "chemical species" above.

> **molecular entity**: Any constitutionally or isotopically distinct atom, molecule, ion, ion pair, radical, radical ion, complex, conformer etc., identifiable as a separately distinguishable entity. Molecular entity is used
> in this Compendium as a general term for singular entities, irrespective of their nature, while chemical species stands for sets or ensembles of molecular entities. Note that the name of a compound may refer to the respective molecular entity or to the chemical species, e.g. methane, may mean a single molecule of CH<sub>4</sub> (molecular entity) or a molar amount, specified or not (chemical species), participating in a reaction. The degree of precision necessary to describe a molecular entity depends on the context.
> For example 'hydrogen molecule' is an adequate definition of a certain molecular entity for some purposes, whereas for others it is necessary to distinguish the electronic state and/or vibrational state and/or nuclear spin, etc. of the hydrogen molecule.

Comment: Species is IMHO not a good fit: OP asks for a term that is the superset of monatomic ions and neutral atoms, whereas species specify subsets even of monatomic ions: Cu⁺, Cu²⁺, and Cu⁰ atoms are different species.

Answer (score 0):

If a statement applies to both atoms as well as monatomic ions (how about plasma?), chances are that it actually applies to the *nucleus* as such.  If it doesn't apply to the nucleus, chances are that your statements do not extend to arbitrary levels of ionization.

So it may be more of a chemical than a linguistic question after all what you may best be writing here.